# What is the equivalent of Wolfram Language's Fold in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In Wolfram Language aka Mathematica ( a Lisp )

```
Fold[g, 0, {a,b,c}]
```

evaluates to

```
g[g[g[0,a],b],c]
```

so when

```
f[x_,y_]:=10 x + y
```

then

```
Fold[f, 0, {1,2,3,4}]
```

evaluates to ( creates a number from the digits )

```
1234
```

What is the equivalent of Wolfram Language's Fold in ClojureScript ?

Comment: isn't this just one form of reduce?

Comment: If you say so, then how is the example done with reduce ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math function fold comes in a few flavors fold left, and fold right which differ in the direction the function is applied. **Clojure's reduce is fold left**

Also in clojure compared to other languages with fold the reducing function will be called with several different numbers of arguments.

first lets define a function that tells us it's args

```
user> (defn ++ [& args]
        (println "++ called with" args)
        (apply + args))
#'user/++
```

If your list is empty the reducing function is called with no arguments to produce the "identity" value. for addition identity is zero, for / it's 1, etc.

```
user> (reduce ++ [])
++ called with nil
0
```

for a single item list it's not called at all

```
user> (reduce ++ [1])
1
```

and for the rest of the cases it's called with two arguments and applies the function as if it where a left associated operator (in inflix languages) or just a plain old function call in lisp.

```
user> (reduce ++ [1 2])
++ called with (1 2)
3
user> (reduce ++ [1 2 3])
++ called with (1 2)
++ called with (3 3)
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
(reduce 
  (fn [r x] (+ (* r 10) x)) 
  0 [1 2 3 4])
```

Comment: In Mathematica Fold[f, 0, {1,2,3,a}] would evaluate to 1230+a that is not quite possible in ClojureScript, right?

Comment: I think it depends on the behavior of the function you are passing. For symbolic math, there are libraries like [expresso](https://github.com/clojure-numerics/expresso). Not sure if it's available in clojurescript though.

Comment: Interesting, will check this. For now I am happy with reduce as is.